# d3.json cant read from json file more than one object

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I got a very large .json file containing many objects each on its own line(looong line :))

Im using d3 framework and the problem is that I cannot read the file using

```
d3.json("/try.json", function(error, input) {
    console.log(input);
});
```

if there is more than one line. I got like 100000+ objects(lines) in the file.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'I cannot read'? Is there any error? Can you try printing the error here?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please include the error log so we can examine and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: Oh sry. It says that i got too long string, it can't separate 2 different objects
RangeError : Invalid String Length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found a solution. I can split my jsons using ./jq

Comment: But it would be better to do it in JavaScript and not in separated programm. So the question is still actual.